# Atomic set and get in clojure.core.cache

Tags: caching, clojure

I am currently toying around with [clojure.core.cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache), and I can not figure out how to do an atomic set-and-get operation with it when having a cache miss in a cache stored in an `Atom`.

I am trying to introduce time-based caching into my clojure service to reduce the amount of expensive db-calls on the one hand and to avoid a memory overflow some time in the future if I just use `memoize` (since this should be a long-running service).

Now as it seems to me, the correct way to use the library is to create a cache via one of the factory functions, store it in an atom, and then swapping in the new cache whenever we update it. (see example below from their docu)

```clj
(require '[clojure.core.cache :as cache])

(def cache (atom (cache/fifo-cache-factory {:a 1, :b 2})))

(swap! cache cache/through-cache :d (constantly 13))

;=> {:a 1, :b 3, :d 13}

(swap! cache cache/evict :b)

;=> {:a 1, :d 13}

(get @cache :a)

;=> 1
```

Now what I do not understand is how to do an atomic set-and-get operation, i.e. how to retrieve a value and the cache being filled transparently if necessary.

If I do it via 2 operations it might cause race conditions from my understanding, so it would be unsafe to use in production.

Is there something I am missing?

**Addition:**
I now realized that the get-and-set operation `cache/through` is done atomically and that consequentially every `get` operation will return the same value.

Comment: What is the difference between what you're asking for and what you've already done? `through-cache` seems to be the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atoms guarantee that there won't be a race condition.

Every call to `swap!` uses a CAS operation behind the scenes. That's why the function you need to provide in `swap!` should be side-effect free, because it might be re-tried if another thread got in the way of updating the atom.

Retrieving-and-filling with `through-cache` in a `swap!` is the correct approach, that said, if you need to guarantee that a slow retrieval operation for a value is only done exactly once, you might want to look at `agents`.

See https://clojure.org/reference/agents
esp. this part:
"If during the function execution any other dispatches are made (directly or indirectly), they will be held until after the state of the Agent has been changed."

Comment: Thank you, do you know whether it is possible to retrieve the value directly or do you have to call `through-cache` and `get` everytime?
Somethink like `get-through-cache` which returns a tuple of the cache and the result?

Comment: Seem like you have to do two operations. Either calculate a new value first and then do the `swap!` or calculate a new value during `swap!` . Again, `through-cache` might be called more than once and so does a potential expensive calculation.

Comment: and you are right: It doesn't feel quite right using this cache

Comment: But I think the "expensive" operation in `through-cache` can only be called once per "key" as long as the "value" does not get evicted, or am I wrong in this?